# SCVMM 2012: What is the role of VMM agent? Terms equivalent to VMM agent?

Tags: hyper-v

Context: System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2012 server and Hyper-V 2012 host

A couple of quick questions:

1. Are the following equivalent: guest agent, host agent and VMM agent?
2. What does the VMM agent do? It is required for communication b/w the VMM server and the host? I know that this is a basic question but believe it or not, I haven't been able to find an explanation online...

Thanks

-Rohan.

Answer (score 0):

"Host agent" and "VMM agent" most likely refer to the "System Center Virtual Machine Manager Agent" service installed on a Hyper-V Host. "Guest Agent" is not as precise and rarely used, but probably means the set of Hyper-V services and devices installed on a guest VM as the "Hyper-V Integration Services".

From the "System Center: Virtual Machine Manager Engineering Blog" at [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/scvmm/archive/2011/09/23/vmm-2012-rc-understanding-the-hyper-v-host-addition-operation-if-window-remote-management-winrm-is-configured-using-group-policy-gpo-settings.aspx)

"As part of Hyper-V host addition, VMM installs an agent on the host machine. This agent communicates with the host using Windows Remote Management (WinRM) transport. We configure a listener for the ports that send and receive WS-Management protocol messages using either HTTP or HTTPS on any IP address"

From "Microsoft Hyper-V Integration Services" at [Link](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/Microsoft-Hyper-V-Integration-Services)

"Hyper-V Integration Services is a suite of utilities in Microsoft Hyper-V, designed to enhance the performance of a virtual machine's guest operating system. Hyper-V Integration Services optimizes the drivers of the virtual environments to provide end users with the best possible user experience. The suite improves virtual machine management by replacing generic operating system driver files for the mouse, keyboard, video, network and SCSI controller components. It also synchronizes time between the guest and host operating systems and can provide file interoperability and a heartbeat"

Answer (score 0):

Host Agent is agent communication via SCVMM and the Hyper-v Host 
Guest Agent sn Hyper-V Integration Services on the VM 
VMM Guest is an agent deployed via VMM when provisioning a service